# Remove tuple key dictionary entries if neither tuple element is in other dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with tuples as keys.
And a second dictionary with single element keys.
The values don't matter.

```
dictionary_1 = {("Apple","Banana") : 3,
                 ("Cat","Dog") : 5,
                 ("Spain", "Italy") : 10,
                 ("Chair","Sofa"): 23}

dictionary_2 = {"Denmark" : 4,
                "Apple" : 9,
                "Fish" : 7,
                "Sofa" : 8 }
```

I want to remove keys from dictionary_1 if the either element of the key is one of the keys in dictionary_2

So solution would be:

```
#Some code
print(dictionary_1)
#The remaining key value pairs would be:
{("Cat","Dog") : 5,
 ("Spain", "Italy") : 10}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you actually tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `for key in dict` syntax to iterate over a dictionary's keys:

```
dictionary_1 = {("Apple","Banana") : 3,
                 ("Cat","Dog") : 5,
                 ("Spain", "Italy") : 10,
                 ("Chair","Sofa"): 23}

dictionary_2 = {"Denmark" : 4,
                "Apple" : 9,
                "Fish" : 7,
                "Sofa" : 8 }

new_dict = {}
for i in dictionary_1:
    if i[0] not in dictionary_2 and i[1] not in dictionary_2:
        new_dict[i] = dictionary_1[i]

print(new_dict) # {('Spain', 'Italy'): 10, ('Cat', 'Dog'): 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) and [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) makes short work of this problem:

```
>>> dictionary_1 = {fruits: n 
                    for fruits, n in dictionary_1.items()
                    if set(fruits).isdisjoint(dictionary_2)}
{('Cat', 'Dog'): 5, ('Spain', 'Italy'): 10}
```

This says:

- Reassign *dictionary_1* to a new dictionary of fruit tuples mapped to numbers
- Take the key/value pairs from the items of the original dictionary
- Include the pair only is there is no overlap between the fruit tuple and keys of the second dictionary.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hmm, that's probably a bit more efficient than my `some()` answer, huh?

Comment: This is great! I assume .isdisjoint(dictionary_2) implicitly refers to dictionary_2's keys? Does it coerce it to be a set? Thank you!

Comment: @MarkMeyer For large `dictionary_2`, I think yours is much faster.

Comment: @MarkMeyer All the answers so far are good.  Each one teaches something different about Python.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Benchmark of your two expressions and one from me: https://repl.it/repls/OptimisticMisguidedBug

Comment: @Jamalan It doesn't convert to a set, it just loops over the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new dictionary with a dict comprehension and leverage `some()` for the test:

```
dictionary_1 = {("Apple","Banana") : 3,
                 ("Cat","Dog") : 5,
                 ("Spain", "Italy") : 10,
                 ("Chair","Sofa"): 23}

dictionary_2 = {"Denmark" : 4,
                "Apple" : 9,
                "Fish" : 7,
                "Sofa" : 8 }

{k:v for k,v in dictionary_1.items() 
 if not any(t in dictionary_2 for t in k)}
# {('Cat', 'Dog'): 5, ('Spain', 'Italy'): 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the dictionary keys:

```
ret = {}
for x, y in dictionary_1:
    if x not in dictionary_2 and y in dictionary_2:
       ret[(x, y)] = dictionary_1[x, y]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion with dictionary comprehension:

```
dictionary_1 = {("Apple","Banana") : 3,
                ("Cat","Dog") : 5,
                ("Spain", "Italy") : 10,
                ("Chair","Sofa"): 23}

dictionary_2 = {"Denmark" : 4,
                "Apple" : 9,
                "Fish" : 7,
                "Sofa" : 8 }

result = {(k1, k2): dictionary_1[k1, k2] for k1, k2 in dictionary_1 if k1 not in dictionary_2 and k2 not in dictionary_2}

print(result)

# output: {('Cat', 'Dog'): 5, ('Spain', 'Italy'): 10}
```